# Python isnumeric function works only on unicode

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if a string is numeric or not, using the `isnumeric` function, but the results are not as expected. The function works only if it's a unicode string.

```
>>> a=u'1'
>>> a.isnumeric()
True
>>> a='1'
>>> a.isnumeric()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
```

`isnumeric` works only if its unicode. Any reason why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Often you will want to check if a string in Python is a number. This
>   happens all the time, for example with user input, fetching data from
>   a database (which may return a string), or reading a file containing
>   numbers. Depending on what type of number you are expecting, you can
>   use several methods. Such as parsing the string, using regex, or
>   simply attempting to cast (convert) it to a number and see what
>   happens. **Often you will also encounter non-ASCII numbers, encoded in
>   Unicode. These may or may not be numbers. For example ๒, which is 2 in
>   Thai.** However © is simply the copyright symbol, and is obviously not a
>   number.

link : http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python-including-unicode/

Answer (score 15):

Just different name.

'1'.isdigit()
True

Comment: u'1.5'.isnumeric() = False, use isdigit or write your own function.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), `isnumeric` is only present for unicode objects:

> The following methods are present only on unicode objects:
>
> unicode.isnumeric()
>
> Return True if there are only numeric characters in S, False otherwise. Numeric characters include digit characters, and all characters that have the Unicode numeric value property, e.g. U+2155, VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH.

Answer (score 2):

`isnumeric()` has extended support for different [numeral systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system) in Unicode strings.

In Americas and Europe the [Hindu-Arabic numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) is used which consists of 0123456789 digits.

The Hindu-Arabic numerals are also called European digits by the Unicode.

The are other numeral systems available such as:

- Roman numerals
- Ancient Greek numerals
- Tamil numerals
- Japaneese numerals
- Chineese numerals
- Korean numerals

More information about numeral systems can be found here: wikiwand.com/en/Numerals_in_Unicode#/Numerals_by_script

Unicode `subscript`, `superscript` and `fractions` are also considered valid numerals by the `isnumeric()` function.

---

You can use the isnumeric() function below to check if a string is a non-unicode number.

```
l = ['abc' + chr(255), 'abc', '123', '45a6', '78b', u"\u2155", '123.4', u'\u2161', u'\u2168']

def isnumeric(s):
    '''Returns True for all non-unicode numbers'''
    try:
        s = s.decode('utf-8')
    except:
        return False

    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except:
        return False


for i in l:
    print i, 'isnumeric:', isnumeric(i)

print '--------------------'
print u'\u2169', 'isnumeric', u'\u2169'.isnumeric()
print u'\u2165', 'isnumeric', u'\u2165'.isnumeric()
```

Edit: I'll update this post as soon as I have enough reputation to add more than 2 links to this answer.