# Why isn't isnumeric working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was going through a very simple python3 guide to using string operations and then I ran into this weird error:

```
In [4]: # create string
        string = 'Let\'s test this.'

        # test to see if it is numeric
        string_isnumeric = string.isnumeric()

Out [4]: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
         <ipython-input-4-859c9cefa0f0> in <module>()
                    3 
                    4 # test to see if it is numeric
              ----> 5 string_isnumeric = string.isnumeric()

         AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
```

The problem is that, as far as I can tell, `str` **[DOES](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm)** have an attribute, `isnumeric`.

Comment: Not in Python 2, change that string to a unicode string.

Comment: Try using `isdigit` instead.

Comment: Found the answer: The text is unicode in Py3 by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863696/python-isnumeric-function-works-only-on-unicode?rq=1

Comment: Post that as an answer with explanation. Accept it. Question resolved.

Answer (score 25):

No, `str` objects do not have an `isnumeric` method. `isnumeric` is only available for unicode objects. In other words:

```
>>> d = unicode('some string', 'utf-8')
>>> d.isnumeric()
False
>>> d = unicode('42', 'utf-8')
>>> d.isnumeric()
True
```

Answer (score 6):

`isnumeric()` only works on Unicode strings. To define a string as Unicode you could change your string definitions like so:

```
In [4]:
        s = u'This is my string'

        isnum = s.isnumeric()
```

This will now store False.

Note: I also changed your variable name in case you imported the module string.

Answer (score 6):

One Liners:

```
unicode('200', 'utf-8').isnumeric() # True
unicode('unicorn121', 'utf-8').isnumeric() # False
```

Or

```
unicode('200').isnumeric() # True
unicode('unicorn121').isnumeric() # False
```

Answer (score 5):

if using python 3 wrap string around **str** as shown below

> str('hello').isnumeric()

This way it behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have a strange case where I needed a script to work in both Python2 & Python3. In case anyone else finds themselves in that situation, here's what I did:

```
s = "123"
try:
    isnum = s.isnumeric()
except AttributeError:
    isnum = unicode(s).isnumeric()
```