# Python Alpha Numeric Fails, but Alpha works

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am trying to strip a string of all non-numeric characters, and I have read [Why isn't isnumeric working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183868/why-isnt-isnumeric-working), or that I must have a unicode string.  However, since `is.alnum()` and `is.alpha()` both don't require unicode and work on strings, what is the difference (if any) between

```
"".join([a for a in foo if a.isalnum() and not a.isalpha()])

"".join([a for a in foo if a.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: Do you have a string that gives different results for each of the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are characters that are both numeric and alphabetic:

```
>>> '㒃'.isalnum()
True
>>> '㒃'.isalpha()
True
>>> '㒃'.isnumeric()
True
>>> '㒃'.isalnum() and not '㒃'.isalpha()
False
```

Note that you can convert that symbol to a number using `unicodedata.numeric`:

```
>>> unicodedata.numeric('㒃')
2.0
```

---

the `isalnum` and `isalpha` method for the `bytes` class return the result expect for ASCII characters, but at that point `bytes` lack the `isnumeric` method which is unicode only. Note that if you restrict yourself to 7bit ASCII then `isdigit` is equivalent to `isalnum() and not isalpha()`.

---

you can find all differences with a simple `for` loop:

```
>>> for i in range(0x110000):
...     c = chr(i)
...     num1 = c.isnumeric()
...     num2 = c.isalnum() and not c.isalpha()
...     if num1 ^ num2:
...         print('Difference:', c, '(', i, ')', num1, num2)
... 
Difference: 㐅 ( 13317 ) True False
Difference: 㒃 ( 13443 ) True False
Difference: 㠪 ( 14378 ) True False
Difference: 㭍 ( 15181 ) True False
Difference: 一 ( 19968 ) True False
Difference: 七 ( 19971 ) True False
Difference: 万 ( 19975 ) True False
Difference: 三 ( 19977 ) True False
Difference: 九 ( 20061 ) True False
Difference: 二 ( 20108 ) True False
# ... more ...
```

Comment: Are there any examples in the English language where this would be different, or is more of a language thing

Comment: @qwertylpc Do you realize that **the whole point** of having unicode and methods like `isnumeric` etc. is to handle *all* possible languages? If you don't care for things that are outside of 7bit ASCII obviously a lot of things become useless. The problem is that you can write your code thinking that, and when a user will try to register or input something into your application it will crash badly cause you forgot that most of the world doesn't share your assumption.

Comment: Yes and you don't need that attitude when responding, I asked a valid question