# Are there methods that should be downloaded into my python?

Tags: python, isnumeric

I entered this code on my text editor and it results in an error. So, do I need to download any kind of files for my Python edition in order to use this `isnumeric` method?

```
txt = "565543"
x = txt.isnumeric()
print(x)
```

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't isnumeric working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183868/why-isnt-isnumeric-working)

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

isnumeric is a inbuilt function. maybe due to your python version or python files the function is not working. try installing python 3.6.8, it will work now and i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you are using an older version of Python.

In older versions of Python `isnumeric()` only works on Unicode objects

**Try running the code this way:**

```
txt = u"565543" 

x = txt.isnumeric()

print(x)
```