# remove-uppercase-lowercase-special-numeric-and-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this coding question but my solution is not printing the expected resuls
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-uppercase-lowercase-special-numeric-and-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string/?ref=rp

I'm trying to solve this without 'regex' as shown in the page

```
str = 'GFGgfg123$%'


def remover(input):
    all_lower = []
    all_upper = []
    all_special = []
    all_numeric = []
    all_non_numeric = []

    for i in input:
        # print(i)
        if i.islower() or not i.isupper():
            all_lower.append(i)

        elif not i.islower():
            all_upper.append(i)

        elif not i.isalpha():
            all_special.append(i)

        elif not i.isnumeric():
            all_numeric.append(i)

        elif i.isnumeric():
            all_non_numeric.append(i)

    print("After removing uppercase characters:", ''.join(all_lower))
    print("After removing lowercase characters:", ''.join(all_upper))
    print("After removing allspecial characters:", ''.join(all_special))
    print("After removing allnumeric characters:", ''.join(all_numeric))
    print("After removing allnonnumeric characters:", ''.join(all_numeric))


remover(str)
```

What I'm getting

```
    After removing uppercase characters: gfg123$%
    After removing lowercase characters: GFG
    After removing allspecial characters:
    After removing allnumeric characters:
    After removing allnonnumeric characters:
```

why this is happening ?
I searched islpha https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isalpha.asp
The isalpha() method returns True if all the characters are alphabet letters (a-z).

Example of characters that are not alphabet letters: (space)!#%&? etc.

isnumeric is not working either because of python thinks them string ? I suppose.
and finally I would appricate time and space complexity why time complexit O(N) and space O(1) for this problem ?
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isnumeric.asp

Comment: What? What's the question??

Comment: This code can't possibly run, please share the entire script, or at least a script that actually produces the output you've shared. It looks like there's some indentation errors and the `print(remover(str))` is probably part of your code outside the function? (I made the edit for you, also removing typos that would cause errors - you should run code you post before posting)

Comment: @Stef its not printing:) the results. Why the functions are not working :)

Comment: It's incredibly hard to understand what you're trying to do. But I suspect these `if / elif / elif /elif` should be rewritten as independent ifs: `if / if / if / if`

Comment: Also, never call a variable `str` in python. It doesn't immediately produce an error, but might cause unexpected effects. `str` is already the name of the builtin class `str` that handles strings. If you shadow that name, strange things might happen.

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you *expected* from the script. Your script produces the output you shared because that's what the code you wrote does. I can get some idea of what you tried to do from the naming, but there's a lot of inconsistency there, so unless you share what you expected the output to be, it's impossible to say what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @Grismar trying to solve this question. Actually I'm suspecting that you even clicked the geekforgeeks link.

Comment: I don't click links in questions unless I have to, since your question is supposed to have relevent information to the question in the body text. It's OK to include links for reference, but your question shouldn't depend on them. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Grismar FYI you can use [short links in comments](/editing-help#comment-formatting). `[ask]` renders as [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea thanks, I'm aware - but for links that short, I think it's beneficial that it actually shows the reader that they're not being taken off the site

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, you are using `elif` instead of `if`, so a character from the `input` will go at most in one of the lists you have defined, based on the first `if`/`elif` condition the given character would match against. So this approach won't work in your case, since the required sets are not disjoint sets and the same character would be part of multiple required lists.

I would also suggest changing the names of your lists, as they are misleading. e.g. content of the `all_lower` in your code is going to be characters that are **NOT** lowercase.

For removing non-special characters, you can use `isalnum()`, which matches against `alphanumerical` characters.

In python2, the `isnumeric()` method only works on unicode strings, while in python3 it works fine on strings. More details about this behavior - [Why isn't isnumeric working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183868/why-isnt-isnumeric-working)

Here's the updated python3 code -

```
str = 'GFGgfg123$%'

def remover(input):
    non_lower = []
    non_upper = []
    non_special = []
    non_numeric = []
    numeric = []

    for i in input:
        # print(i)
        if i.islower() or not i.isupper():
            non_lower.append(i)

        if not i.islower():
            non_upper.append(i)

        if i.isalnum():
            non_special.append(i)

        if not i.isnumeric():
            non_numeric.append(i)

        if i.isnumeric():
            numeric.append(i)

    print("Original string: ", input)
    print("After removing uppercase characters:", ''.join(non_lower))
    print("After removing lowercase characters:", ''.join(non_upper))
    print("After removing all special characters:", ''.join(non_special))
    print("After removing all numeric characters:", ''.join(non_numeric))
    print("After removing all non-numeric characters:", ''.join(numeric))

remover(str)
```

This prints -

```
Original string:  GFGgfg123$%
After removing uppercase characters: gfg123$%
After removing lowercase characters: GFG123$%
After removing all special characters: GFGgfg123
After removing all numeric characters: GFGgfg$%
After removing all non-numeric characters: 123
```